# Term for the neglect of a child or animal

Tags: single-word-requests, legalese

I am looking for a term describing the neglect of a living being under one's responsibility, such as a child or animal.

Spontaneously I thought of court procedures, with the sad cases of children being neglected, which I believe is categorised as child abuse. The same applies for pets and livestock.

Abuse may imply things such as physical harm though, which I would like to exclude.

I would like to be able to put it in the phrase

> Did you hear, so-and-so were caught with _____!

Are there any terms, legal or otherwise, that may be of use?

I searched Merriam-Webster, but primarily came across words neglecting property/infrastructure or official duties, such as abandonment or misprision.

Oxford Dictionaries also didn't offer many alternatives, as far as I could tell.

Comment: The term is negligence. But you can't be "caught with it": you can be charged with negligence.

Comment: @Lambie You can't be charged with negligence as it's not a crime: in common law jurisdictions, _negligence_ is a tort, a civil matter. _Criminal negligence_ is terminology used in many jurisdictions... but that refers to a state of mind required for conviction - the _mens rea_ - not to a crime in itself. (Vehicular homicide/death by dangerous driving, manslaughter/second degree murder and negligent endangerment are all examples of specific crimes with a _criminal negligence_ or equivalent level of intent.)

Comment: Besides what you spontaneiously thought of, have you researched the dictionary or any thesaurus for related words or expressions?  Those examples would be helpful in your question,

Comment: @KristinaLopez Thank you for pointing it out. My question has been updated concerning your question.

Comment: Such a question may have different answers in different jurisdictions; it can thus be answered only within the context of a specified legal system. Within such a context, it would be a legal question, and thus outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neglect *is* the right term for this, see for example [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neglect).

> Neglect is a form of abuse where the perpetrator, who is responsible for caring for someone who is unable to care for themselves, fails to do so.

Physical harm is not mentioned at all.

Further examples:

> **Animal neglect** or abandonment is a common type of animal cruelty where people do not provide adequate care for animals in their charge.

<sub>(source: [USLegal.com](https://definitions.uslegal.com/a/animal-neglect/))</sub>

> **Child neglect** is a form of child abuse, and is a deficit in meeting a child's basic needs, including the failure to provide adequate health care, supervision, clothing, nutrition, housing as well as their physical, emotional, social, educational and safety needs.

<sub>(source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_neglect))</sub>

Comment: Is there a combined term?

Comment: @ALambentEye I thought you were attending to other matters?

Comment: @Lordology I am, this was sent off before I averted my attention. I am still unavailable.

Comment: @ALambentEye are you back?

Answer (score 1):

**abuse**  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse)

> the mistreatment of people, systems or animals

If you **abuse** an entity, it means you are hurting that entity, mentally, emotionally, or physically.

As in:

> Did you hear, so-and-so were caught abusing animals!

and

> Did you hear, so-and-so were caught abusing children!